# Azure B2C SPA app with custom policy gives Sign In error "Invalid username or password”

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, single-page-application, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Our SPA app and Web API were working well with the standard SignUpSignIn user flow. When we switched to using a custom policy while keeping the same App Registrations, Sign In always displays “Invalid username or password” [1]. (Sign Up and Sign Out work).

To remedy the issue, we created new App Registrations as per [Microsoft Custom Policy Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)

- As stated, we used “Allow public client flows.”
- Now the signin/signup page displays “The provided application with ID xxx is not valid against this service.” (error AADB2C90068). This happens whenever we use account type “Accounts in this organizational directory only”
- If we use “Accounts in any identity provider”, we go back to getting “Invalid username or password”
- Switching the front-end to “SPA” instead of “Public client/native (mobile & desktop)” doesn’t help.

Strangely, we did find a configuration that works: Following the tutorial exactly (Allow public client flows + Accounts in this org directory only + Public client/native platform) but leaving the front-end SPA app pointing to the old app registrations. Obviously we can’t leave it like that.

How do we properly solve the “Invalid username or password” issue with an SPA app using a custom policy?

---

[1] The corresponding sign-in log says error 7000218.

Also, TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml does have the correct IDs in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the tool I’ve made: https://aka.ms/iefsetup.

But your issue is definitely due to the way you’ve registered the two app registrations, or inserting the IDs into the XML.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the tool. I ran it, and the setup results screen confirmed the creation of 3 new app registrations (IEF, ProxyIEF, IEF Test App. I pointed our SPA app to the new registrations, and the signin/signup page displays “The provided application with ID xxx is not valid against this service.” (error AADB2C90068).

P.s. The IEF Test App works (a decoded token is displayed by the jwt.ms site.

Comment: Not sure what this means: `I pointed our SPA app to the new registrations`. But follow this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-spa-app#step-2-register-your-spa-and-api

Comment: Usually that error happens when you create an app registration and you didn’t select the default “supported account types” option, which references “user flows”.

Comment: Hi, it meant that our MSAL 2.0 instance's "clientId" was changed to the App registration created by the tool. I followed the guide you suggested, and still end-up with the error Invalid Username/Password at the Azure B2C sign-in page. I did set "Accounts in any identity provider". Note: The tool creates App registrations using the "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<TENANT-NAME>.onmicrosoft.com" paths and these seem deprecated, I tried switching to the Azure B2C path "https://<TENANT-NAME>.b2clogin.com/<TENANT-NAME>.onmicrosoft.com" but this did not help. Any other ideas what may be the issue?

Comment: Did you use a user flow to sign up the account? The only other reason for the error is that the user has forceChangePasswordOnNextLogin attribute set to true, which can happen if you create the user in an unsupported way. But this error would apply to all clientIds. Do not change anything that the tool created. The fact that the test app works means it’s something you created in addition to what the tool created that’s not configured correctly.

Comment: Should I be using the Application ID of the IEF Test App registration, or the Application ID of the ProxyIEF registration when specifying the clientID in the configuration of my SPA application?

Comment: I got it to work, but I'm not sure if it is supposed to work this way. The tool creates 3 App Registrations: IEF, ProxyIEF, and "IEF Test App". If I don't change anything in the IEF and ProxyIEF, and then create a 3rd registration "My Test App" which is like "IEF Test App" but with SPA redirect URIs, and configure our SPA front-end app's code with the Client ID of "My Test App" and the App ID of "IEF", it works. Is 3 App Registrations redundant? (When we were using User Flows instead of Custom Policy, we only had 2 and it worked)

Comment: The IEF and ProxyIEF app should never be used outside of login-interactive technical profile in the custom policy xml. You should create a new App registration, like the “test app”, to connect your SPA app to B2C. Follow this after running the tool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-authentication-sample-spa-app#step-2-register-your-spa-and-api

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by creating two new App Registrations IEF and ProxyIEF that are for use exclusively by the custom policy XML. Our SPA application and it's Web Api back-end each use one additional App Registration as was the case when we were using a User Flow.

Thanks to [Jas Suri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8357357/jas-suri-msft), especially for this comment: *"Do not change anything that the tool created. The fact that the test app works means it’s something you created in addition to what the tool created that’s not configured correctly."*